# How To export the selected rows into an Excel and also download the associated timesheet files?

Tags: javascript, blazor, blazor-server-side

#Blazor#
`var base64 = await ReportManager.ExportToExcelPayrollReport(weekendingdate.Value.ToShortDateString()); await _jsRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync("Download", new { ByteArray = base64, FileName = $"{"Payroll Report"}_{DateTime.Now:ddMMyyyyHHmmss}.xlsx", MimeType = ApplicationConstants.MimeTypes.OpenXml }); _snackBar.Add(string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(_searchString) ? "Payroll Report exported" : "Filtered Payroll Report exported", Severity.Success);`

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Take a look at this, may be usefull
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60547310/blazor-export-to-excel Bye

Comment: No, i want to download Selected Rows Only