# how to open a Save as Dialogue window from c# blazor web app?

Tags: c#, blazor, blazor-server-side, blazor-webassembly, asp.net-blazor

I want to export some data to .CSV file. My requirement is once I click on Export button bellow Save As Dialogue should open.I am using blazor web application and the Export button is placed on blazor web page.

So how to open a Save as Dialogue window from blazor web app?

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Blazor export to excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60547310/blazor-export-to-excel)

Comment: Thnaks but the solution is not for opening a SAVE AS DIALOGUE BOX.

Comment: you cannot open SAVE AS DIALOGUE BOX from web, you can open Download Dialog with "Response" by create a new response on the fly file.